# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: spring, apache, apache-axis

What I am trying to achieve is to upload Temenos T24 Design Studio web services on Axis2.

Unfortunately, I am getting a Class not found error when uploading the service using "aar" (Axis2 archive) file.

I have already deployed Axis2 1.4.4 on IBM Websphere 9.

Note : There has been certain conflicts while deploying Axis2 application on IBM websphere JAX-WS, which I have used this guide to resolve them;
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21315686

Below is the error I am getting;

=================================

This Web axisService has deployment faults

Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext at com.temenos.services.designstudioinstaller.DesignStudioInstallerServiceSpringContext.loadServiceContext(DesignStudioInstallerServiceSpringContext.java:27)[image]

Comment: How are you building this service ?

Comment: @Jangid , This service is provided with Temenos as an .aar file which I am trying to upload to Axis2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the following jar files from the t24lib directory:

1. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-ejb.jar
2. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-ProxyAdaptor.jar
3. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-jws.aar
4. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-provider.jar
5. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-tafj-jws.aar
6. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-tafj-provider.jar

For any service component such as EB_ResourceProviderService, only the below jars must be present within the t24lib directory:

1. EB_ResourceProviderService.jar
2. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-Data.jar
3. t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-t24service.jar

Restart the application server after removing them and the axis2 should deploy successfully.

I had similar error deploying axis2.war inflated with Temenos aar files on JBoss EAP 7.1 and it was solved by removing the duplicated .jar and .aar files in t24lib:

```
[INFO] The t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-tafj-jws.aar service, which is not valid, caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
    at com.temenos.services.resourceprovider.ResourceProviderServiceSpringContext.loadServiceContext(ResourceProviderServiceSpringContext.java:27)
```

Comment: I am using TAFJ R18 SP 1. As a side note if it helps,T24 browser is working fine.

Comment: I eddited my original answer, as I remembered the correct solution. I had the same issue on jBOSS EAP 7.1 Application server.

Comment: t24Lib already didn't have the 6 files you mentioned to remove. But they were under ..Extensions/EB_ResourceProviderService folder and I removed from there instead. Also I verified the availability of 3 files mentioned. However, I still get the same error. Could it be something to do with unavailability or incompatibility of spring resources?

Comment: Extensions/EB_ResourceProviderService seems to be under TEMP.RELEASE? For me the t24lib provided by Temenos had the 6 jar files and thery were registered as modules in JBoss. Are you sure you are looking into the right t24lib? It has to be the one which is provied in Websphere classpath. However, I dont have experience with Websphere setup, the solution worked for me in JBoss.

Comment: Extensions/EB_ResourceProviderServices is not under TEMP.RELEASE. The full path to T24Lib is /project/modelbank/R18MB01/bnk/Lib/T24Lib which is on the TAFJ server and visible to application server.

Comment: What is the difference between t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-tafj-jws.aar and t24-EB_ResourceProviderService-jws.aar ?

I don't think you need both files.